# SQL Server Two-Tier replication - transactional/merge - rows not coming down

Tags: sql-server, merge, replication, transactional

I have a SQL 2000 instance that has database with a transactional publication - tables only. It is subscribed to by a SQL 2005 instance - no problems.

I need to publish some of the tables from this transactional subscription in a merge publication. Right now, I'm using another database in the SQL 2005 instance as the merge subscriber.

The set up looks like this:

SQL2000 --(Transactional)--> SQL2005-1 --(Merge)--> SQL2005-2

The initial snapshot of the SQL2000 publication comes all the way down to the SLQ2005-2 Merge subscriber.

If I update or insert a row on the SQL2000 side, it comes through to the middle SQL2005-1 database. However, these rows do not get propagated through to the SQL2005-2 database. If I manually insert or update a row in the SQL2005-1 database, the change does come through.

It seems as though update or insert triggers that the merge publication works off of are not getting called when the transactional subscription performs the insert or update.

How can I get this to work? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here, but are your 2005-1 to 2005-2 triggers marked as "not for replication" and therefor being skipped with the 2000 to 2005-1 is happening?  Chaining replication is not an easy process and a good amount of the 'wizard' stuff needs to be modified to make it work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152529.aspx